# End of statement expected - defining a variable

Tags: vb.net, variables

I get the error "End of statement expected" when I try and declare the variable VRAM

```
Dim VRAM As String

If VRAMT.Value = 1 Then
    VRAM = 256m
    VRAMT.Value = 2 Then
    VRAM = 512m
    VRAMT.Value = 3 Then
    VRAM = 768m
    VRAMT.Value = 4 Then
    VRAM = 1024m
    VRAMT.Value = 5 Then
    VRAM = 1280m
    VRAMT.Value = 6 Then
    VRAM = 1636m
    VRAMT.Value = 7 Then
    VRAM = 1792m
    VRAMT.Value = 8 Then
    VRAM = 2048m
End If
```

Thanks for any help. It is probably really easy, but I can't seem to work it out :(

Comment: You declared a string, but are trying to assign decimal literals to it. Why would you do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use an `ELSEIF` on each subsequent line after the first `IF`, or use `SELECT CASE` instead.

```
  If VRAMT.Value = 1 Then
        VRAM = 256m
  ELSEIF VRAMT.Value = 2 Then
        VRAM = 512m
  ...
  End If
```

Here's how to do it with `SELECT CASE`

```
Select Case VRAMT.Value
    Case 1
        VRAM = 256m
    Case 2
        VRAM = 512m
    ...
End Select
```

Comment: Doesn't work, I now just get errors on the M, on the end of the number. Is my variable the right type?

Comment: You probably need to make the VRAM variable decimal. If you want to keep it as string, you'll need to surround the VRAM values (e.g. 256M, etc.) in double quotes.